# Wordpress Elementor "Archive posts" needs data from archive into the home page

Tags: php, wordpress, archive, elementor

I have a custom post type of "members". I want to display the members in the home page (https://localhost/wp-elementor/).

On the members page https://localhost/wp-elementor/members/ everything is looking good, because the data is populated there.

I want do make a small preview of the members on the home page, but if I use an "Archive posts" widget from Elementor there, it is not populated with data. How do I get this archive to populate on the home page with all the members that are in my custom post type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use Posts widget, not archive posts https://elementor.com/help/posts-widget-pro/

in the query tab, you can choose what type of posts you wants, it will show the custom post as well

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know this one :)